# Non-vanishing of L-values for twists of Hilbert modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, l-functions

Let $F$ be a real quadratic field, and let $f$ be a Hilbert modular form over $F$ of parallel weight 2.

It's known, by a theorem of Rohrlich, that there exist infinitely many Hecke characters of $F$ such that $L(f, \chi, 1) \ne 0$. Does there always exist a Hecke character *factoring through the norm map to $\mathbf{Q}$* such that this holds?

(There are some statistics due to Ryan et al, https://math.dartmouth.edu/~jvoight/articles/halfhilbert-022218.pdf, which suggest that this should be true for "almost all" quadratic twists coming from $\mathbf{Q}$; but just one character -- not necessarily quadratic -- would be enough for my purposes!)

Comment: I'm sure you already know this; such a character must be a genus character associated to a pair of primitive quadratic Dirichlet characters $\chi_1$, $\chi_2$ modulo fundamental discriminants $D_1, D_2$ such that $D_1 D_2$ is equal to the fundamental discriminant $D$ of $F$.

Comment: No, I don't already know that. Why is it true?

Comment: (This assertion, if true, would imply that there are only finitely many possible $\chi$. This would contradict the asymptotics of Ryan et al, so I'm a bit sceptical.)

Comment: Apologies, this is only the case when you are talking about class group characters. In general, the picture is as follows. Let $\omega : F^{\times} \backslash \mathbb{A}_F^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ be a Hecke character, and suppose that this factors through the norm map $\mathrm{N}_{F/\mathbb{Q}}$: $\omega = \chi \circ \mathrm{N}_{F/\mathbb{Q}}$ for some Hecke character $\chi : \mathbb{Q}^{\times} \backslash \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$...

Comment: ... Then the  automorphic induction of $\omega$ is the Eisenstein series $\chi \boxplus \chi \chi_{F/\mathbb{Q}}$, where $\chi_{F/\mathbb{Q}} : \mathbb{Q}^{\times} \backslash \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is the quadratic Hecke character associated to $F$.

Comment: This shows that you can index such characters by Dirichlet characters. An analytic number theorist's approach now would be to consider the average of $|L(f,\chi,1)|^2$ over Dirichlet characters of conductor at most $Q$ and hope to prove an asymptotic as $Q \to \infty$. The size of the indexing family is roughly $Q^2$, whereas the conductor of the square of the $L$-function is roughly $Q^8$, so the ratio of the log of conductors is $4$, which is precisely the barrier at which we can hope to prove an asymptotic. (I.e. if it were $>4$ then we probably wouldn't stand a chance.)